# How to interact with lazy load HTML elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, lazy-loading

I have a chrome extension that takes all the items on a page and puts them into an array.

```
function getAllItems() {
    return document.getElementsByClassName('items')
}
```

However, only 24 items automatically load. There may be a lot more that load when you scroll to the bottom of the page.

How can I interact with these lazy-load items?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in the DOM for specific node, so you can check if there're more elements added dynamically, and re-run your code!

check this example from MDN:

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Zac, it's a very useful step in the right direction. The changes in the DOM (more items loading) don't occur until a user scrolls to the bottom of their page. I was hoping to be able to interact with theses elements without the user having to scroll down themselves. Any thoughts?

Comment: As far as I understand from your main question, these elements don't exist at all before scrolling down, is it correct?

Comment: Exactly. They only appear when the user scrolls down.

Comment: So you can't interact with them before they are in the DOM, you can detect DOM changes, or even trigger the scroll event programmatically, but you need them to be loaded in DOM first :)

Comment: Was thinking it was looking too simple :) Thanks @Zac!

Answer (score -1):

You might need to call the function when all the items are loaded by using `"DOMContentLoaded"` event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function getAllItems() {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('items')
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: DOMContentLoaded is called only once when the page loads. The OP is asking about elements pulled from a service after the DOMContentLoaded event has occurred.